# Number of empty boxes when you put iteratively 10 boxes in a random box

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

We are given a large box and in the first turn we put 10 smaller boxes in it. In the
next turn we choose some of those smaller boxes and in each of them we again put 10 boxes. We repeat this process some number of times, putting 10 new boxes in some of the empty boxes. In the end we get 2021 non-empty boxes. How many empty boxes do we have?

**Attempt**

I tried to imagine it as a graph $G$ which is a tree. The root is the vertex $v_0$ (our biggest box) and has degree 10 since we place 10 boxes inside of it. Then we choose a few of those boxes and place another 10 boxes in it. In my graph the non-empty boxes correspond to vertices with degree 10 (if its the first box) or degree 11. Any vertex with degree 0 is an empty box. So I'm interested in the number of leaves in this graph.

I know the following formula which has to hold in every graph:

$\sum_{v \in V(G)}d(v) = 2|E|$ i.e. the sum of all the degrees is twice the number of edges.

Applied to my case we have that:

$\sum_{v \in V(G)}d(v) = 10 + 2020 \cdot 11+ \text{"number of leaves"} = 2|E|$. Now how many edges do I have in my graph? We will draw an edge only for non-empty boxes and then we will draw 10 edges. Since we have $2021$ non-empty boxes, we will draw $2021 \cdot 10$ edges i.e. $20210$ edges. So I have the following equation:

$\sum_{v \in V(G)}d(v) = 10 + 2020 \cdot 11+ \text{"number of leaves"} = 2 \cdot 20210 \iff \text{"number of leaves"} = 18190$.

Is that a valid reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasononing and answer are both correct.

Here I want to provide a bit more simple solution. Let think that in every turn you choose exactly one empty box and put $10$ smaller boxes into it. Each such operation increases the number of non-empty boxes by $1$ (and initially this number is $0$) and increases number of empty boxes by $10 - 1 = 9$. Therefore this operation will be done $2021$ times and the total number of empty boxes will be $1 + 2021 \cdot 9 = 18190$.